# mongodb connection thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb, design-patterns, database-connection

I am using the following code based on some tutorials to connect to the mongo database.

I have some doubts regarding the design:

1. Is it okay to call the MongoConnection.getDB() function from multiple threads simultaneously?
2. If not, should I make it synchronized?
3. If the design has issues, what kind of unwanted impact could it have?

I am new to mongodb so my question may sound a bit naive.

```
public class MongoConnection {

    private static MongoClient mongoClient = null;

    private static String IP = "mongodb://user:pwd@localhost:27017/?authSource=demodb&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1";
    private static String DATABASE = "demodb";

    static {
        mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(IP));
    }

    private MongoConnection() {

    }

    public static DB getDB() {
        return mongoClient.getDB(DATABASE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/driver/getting-started/quick-start/):

> The MongoClient instance represents a pool of connections to the database; you will only need one instance of class MongoClient even with multiple threads.

And from the [previous versions' quick start guides](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/quick-tour/):

> The MongoClient class is designed to be thread safe and shared among threads. Typically you create only 1 instance for a given database cluster and use it across your application.`

So, `MongoClient.getDb(..)` should not have any problem among threads

Comment: Looks like a citation. You are supposed to specify the source when using a citation. Essentially needs **strict emphasis** on NOT attempting to share a database connection itself. This is pretty age old with database connections  or any "stateful" network connection in general. You simply don't fork or spawn threads on these.

Comment: Edited while trying to attach the url, it was supposed to be a citation, hence the \` \`.

Comment: Actually "citation" uses the `>` the other ticks are for "code". See. edited.

Comment: @NeilLunn I had read that in the docs but I still had this confusion. So I guess my design is okay?

Comment: @Sid Sure. iAlex has pointed you at the relevant part. The class is essentially intended as a singleton which you use methods like `getDB()` on in the other parts of your application. Drivers for other languages general are not "fork safe" and with worker processes it's generally recommended that you would create separate connections and pools for workers. "Thread Safe" however for Java is fine as it's designed to grab from the single pool in different operations among threads. In brief, if the official documentation says it's okay, then it probably is as someone has tested it.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I have a question. Can I share one mongodb client connection with multilple threads like I can do this in Couchbase ?